# On a rainy day, a man is running on a hilly terrain in such a way that he is always finding the rain drops hitting him vertically

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

It is assumed that rainfall is uniform in the whole terrain from O to E(figure attached) When the man was at rest on stretch OA, he found the rainfall at an angle of $30^o $ with the vertical.

What will be the ratio of the magnitude of velocity of rain observed on stretch AB to the magnitude of velocity of man on stretch BC?

[image: Figure]

---

I decided to post this after spending a lot of time on this and trying a lot of different ways to get to the answer.  I believe what the book means by magnitude of velocity of rain 'observed' is the velocity of rain with respect to the man.

So, **in stretch AB**, using the condition that the man runs such that he always finds the rain hitting him vertically,

we can equate the component of velocity of the rain along the velocity of the man so that they cancel each other out and the man ends up observing only the component of velocity of rain which is perpendicular to the direction of his motion.

So the velocity observed by the man is only the vertical component of the velocity of the rain.

> $v_1=v_{rain}sin 30^o$

This figure might help you understand how I came to this conclusion:

[image]

Coming to BC, the man's velocity would simply be equal to the rain's horizontal component hence,

> $v_2=v_{rain} sin 30^o$

But I am a bit confused. The paths of the man keep varying along his journey. But the velocity of rain that he experiences always stays normal to his motion. How is that possible?

One thought that came in my head was that the man's running velocity also keeps changing according to the situations. But then, wouldn't that cause error in the calculations I performed to find the ratio($\frac{v_1}{v_2}$)?

Comment: Indeed, if the rain is always falling straight down onto the man, that means his horizontal velocity must always equal the horizontal velocity of the rain. Since the rain is constant but the man's angle of movement changes, his speed must also change between sections (to keep vH constant). Since we know the horizontal velocity of the rain is always 0 with respect to the man, the only difference can be in the vertical velocity of the rain hitting him. On flat ground, that's just the vertical velocity of the rain, but on a slope, you need to add/subtract the vertical velocity of the man.